# When will the real numbers be Borel?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

In set theory Borel sets are important, but we don't actually care about the sets. We can about the Borel codes. Namely, the algorithm to generate a given Borel set starting with the basic open sets (intervals with rational end points, or some other canonical basis) and taking countable unions, complements, and so on.

There are many proofs and arguments that look like "A Borel set $X$ is in a certain ideal if and only if it does not contain a real in a certain generic extension". And while that *does* give us some useful information about ground model sets via generic extensions, it is not $X$ itself that contains that generic real, but rather the "re-computation of $X$ from its code".

But what about the *set* $X$? Clearly you cannot add elements to sets with forcing. When does $X$ remain Borel? Or just generally, when does $\Bbb R$ itself stay Borel in its generic extension?

> Is there some relatively simple and non-trivial condition on a generic real $c$ for which ground model Borel sets remain Borel? What about when adding uncountably many reals?

Clearly, if we collapse $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $\aleph_0$, then all the sets of reals become countable and thus Borel. But I'm looking for something a bit more robust, such as a simple criterion to check against Cohen, Sacks, Random, etc.

Comment: Since many of the "reals of interest" can be given as "avoiding an ideal of sets of reals", phrasing an answer in terms of properties of said ideals is also an interesting (albeit partial) answer.

Comment: This paper of Velickovic and Woodin is relevant : https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9501203       They show that if M is an inner model of set theory and the set of reals in M is analytic then either all reals are in M or else $\aleph_{1}^{M}$ is countable. This doesn't quite answer your question, but I think there's other stuff in there that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's interesting. I remembered something like this about $L$, but a general statement is even better. I'll look at the paper later today.

Answer (score 17):

I think that  Groszek and Slaman's result (see https://www.jstor.org/stable/421023?seq=1) gives a satisfying answer to your question.

Groszek  and Slaman's result says that given any inner model $M$ of $ZFC$, $\mathbb{R}\subset M$ if and only if there is a perfect set $A\subset M$.

A immediate conclusion of the result is that for any inner model $M$ of $ZFC$ and an $M$-Borel set $A$, $A$ remains to be Borel in any  extension $N$ of $M$ with $\mathbb{R}^M\neq \mathbb{R}^N$ if and only if $A$ is countable in $N$.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks! I only knew this result where $M=L$.

Comment: I think this is not quite what Groszek and Slaman prove, and, unless I'm missing something, what you have written is not true as stated. (I assume you are quoting Theorem 2.4 in their paper, but this theorem has an extra combinatorial hypothesis, and does not apply to arbitrary pairs of models.) Velickovic and Woodin prove in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9501203.pdf that there are models $M,N$ of ZFC such that $M \subseteq N$, $N$ contains reals not in $M$, and yet the reals of $M$ form an uncountable $F_\sigma$ subset of reals in $N$. (See theorems 7 and 8 in the linked paper.)

Comment: It depends on the definition of ``inner model". Groszek-Slaman condition is not just a pure combinatoric one but a kind of inner model condition. Essentially it says that if $M=\bigcup_{\alpha}M_{\alpha}$, i.e. $M$ is built level by level, and master codes cofinally range over $\theta$, where $\theta$ is the least ordinal so that $M\setminus M_{\theta}$ does not contain a real, then G-S conclusion holds.

Comment: I see -- thanks for explaining. Does this condition always hold between a ground model and one of its forcing extensions?

Comment: @WillBrian it does not. Forcing with Namba over a model of $\mathbb{c}= \aleph_2$ adds a countable sequence of reals which cannot be covered by countable ground-model sets. The countable covering condition in that paper is designed to exclude the example of Velickovic and Woodin (which was a refinement of the rough "forcing with Namba over the failure of CH" idea.)

Comment: Link to the paper [A Basis Theorem for Perfect Sets](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=A+Basis+Theorem+for+Perfect+Sets) seems to be dead. In case it is useful for somebody, I'll add at least in a comment links to 
[doi: 10.2307/421023](https://doi.org/10.2307/421023) and
[jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/421023).
The paper is freely available also here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/04-toc.htm

Comment: @Martin any reason why you didn't edit the post itself?

Comment: Just to be sure I didn't misunderstand: this doesn't fully answer the original question, does it? It gives a condition on some set $A$ for $A$ to remain Borel under *every* extension, but the question was to find a condition *on the extension* for $\mathbb{R}$ to remain Borel in a specific extension. Right, @AsafKaragila?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: Well, if $\Bbb R$ remains Borel, it is countable, so all its subsets are countable; on the other hand, if it doesn't, then it is an example of a Borel set which is no longer Borel.

Comment: Wait, what are the quantifiers in the statement “$A$ remains to be Borel in any extension $N$ of $M$ with $\mathbb{R}^M\neq \mathbb{R}^N$ if and only if $A$ is countable in $N$”? Does this mean that “for any extension $N$, ($A$ remains Borel iff it is countable)” or “$A$ is countable iff (for any extension $N$ it remains Borel)”? I read it as the latter. Is it actually the former? (The former certainly answers the question, but then the syntax is awfully confusing!)